# How to get custom user profile properties in SharePoint 2013 restful api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

In my Sp2013, I tried this link

```
http://mysite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

and it gets all properties including the custom managed ones from crawling. And one of them is called `Office` which comes in the xml from above link.

This is in the big xml thats returned

```
            <d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
                <d:Key>Office</d:Key>
                <d:Value>12-R</d:Value>
                <d:ValueType>Edm.String</d:ValueType>
            </d:element>
```

But then if I try this

```
http://mysite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/Office
```

it says `Office` is not found...

How can I get it to return that?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried with other property? may be property name is different what you typing...also try this way http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureUrl

Comment: I tried it, and the pictureUrl, and also even email works. Its just the custom managed ones that don't work.

Comment: have u tried Select?

Comment: yess and it didnt work

Comment: Not sure if it's helpful but we use CSWP to achieve this since we can do dynamic query in CSWP. All we put is "Office:{User.Office}" then the search will automatically filter on current user's office, or you can default to current user's office and sort by that property.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get only the specific property value then use "getuserprofilepropertyfor" & pass the current user login name

```
$.ajax({
      url: "http://<site url>/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager
        /getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountName=@v, propertyname='Office')
            ?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Csekhar%mydomain.onmicrosoft.com'",
      type: "GET",
      headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
      success: successHandler,
      error: errorHandler
    });
```

Comment: this worked, but how can I do this for current user?

Comment: use _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName to pass the current user login name if you are not an AD user. apply escapeProperly function before adding it to rest call escapeProperly(_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName)

Comment: I tried `alert(_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName);` but it says undefined.

Comment: https://server/site/_api/Web/CurrentUser/LoginName

Comment: But thats then 2 ajax calls (one to get username, then one more to get office). I only want 1 call

Comment: Well. is there any reason you are not using JSOM?.

Comment: As far as i know , /_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/UserProfileProperties is the only endpoint to get the current user properties

Answer (score 1):

Try below approach. It worked fine for me.

```
var siteUrl = "http://mysite";
$.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
             for (var i = 0; i < data.d.UserProfileProperties.results.length; i++)
            {
                if(data.d.UserProfileProperties.results[i].Key == "Office")
                {
                    alert(data.d.UserProfileProperties.results[i].Value);
                }
            }

        },
        error: error
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
http://mysite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountame=@v, propertyname='Office')?@v='*AccountName*'
```